# vim-flake8 started showing D and H errors

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, pyflakes

I have a problem with pyflake8 in vim, he started displaying some errors that he didn't show at all, like this:

```
models.py|1 col 1| D100  Missing docstring in public module
models.py|2 col 1| H306  imports not in alphabetical order (django.db.models, django.contrib.auth.models.user)
models.py|6 col 1| D204  1 blank line required after class docstring (found 0)
models.py|6 col 1| D205  1 blank line required between summary line and description (found 0)
models.py|6 col 1| D209  Multi-line docstring closing quotes should be on a separate line
models.py|6 col 1| D211  No blank lines allowed before class docstring (found 1)
models.py|9 col 1| H405  multi line docstring summary not separated with an empty line
models.py|9 col 53| H403  multi line docstrings should end on a new line
models.py|14 col 1| D210  No whitespaces allowed surrounding docstring text
models.py|14 col 1| D400  First line should end with a period (not '!')
```

I assume that these are some standard pep8 errors, but pyflakes8 didn't show them till today, when I did an upgrade on it. Current version `2.5.4 (pep8: 1.7.0, mccabe: 0.4.0, pep257: 0.2.1.post1, pyflakes: 1.0.0, hacking.core: 0.0.1, ProxyChecker: 0.0.1) CPython 2.7.6 on Linux`
 I did it because vim was showing error that pyflake is not working, after upgrade pyflake was working but it started showing this D and H errors, how to solve this situation?

Comment: Do you not want these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim-flake8 uses the standard flake8 config file `~/.config/flake8`, which can be configured like this example from the [docs](http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html).

```
The user settings are read from the ~/.config/flake8 file 
(or the ~/.flake8 file on Windows). Example:

[flake8]
ignore = E226,E302,E41
max-line-length = 160
exclude = tests/*
max-complexity = 10
```

This looks like it was [changed recently](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8#History).

Comment: So that is the problem, and yes that is the thing I was hopping to find